# How do you bring an Image View below a Text View on the iPad? (On the iPad)

Tags: xcode, ipad

How do you bring an Image View below a Text View on the iPad?

Somehow I have an Image View on top of a Text View and you can't see the text!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Interface Builder, go to the Document window (the view hierachy) and drag the text view *below* the image view.

In code, use the [`-bringSubviewToFront:` method](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW24).